# Unable to PUT to Nest

Tags: python, firebase, nest-api

I am unable to PUT Nest data like `ambient_temperature_f` to https://developer-api.nest.com or the redirected Firebase URL. I suspect there is something specific to the Nest that will need to be tweaked in the Firebase module I am using (https://ozgur.github.io/python-firebase/).

From `firebase.py`:

```
@http_connection(60)
def make_put_request(url, data, params, headers, connection):
    """
    Helper function that makes an HTTP PUT request to the given firebase
    endpoint. Timeout is 60 seconds.
    `url`: The full URL of the firebase endpoint (DSN appended.)
    `data`: JSON serializable dict that will be stored in the remote storage.
    `params`: Python dict that is appended to the URL like a querystring.
    `headers`: Python dict. HTTP request headers.
    `connection`: Predefined HTTP connection instance. If not given, it
    is supplied by the `decorators.http_connection` function.

    The returning value is a Python dict deserialized by the JSON decoder. However,
    if the status code is not 2x or 403, an requests.HTTPError is raised.

    connection = connection_pool.get_available_connection()
    response = make_put_request('http://firebase.localhost/users',
                                '{"1": "Ozgur Vatansever"}',
                                {'X_FIREBASE_SOMETHING': 'Hi'}, connection)
    response => {'1': 'Ozgur Vatansever'} or {'error': 'Permission denied.'}
    """
    timeout = getattr(connection, 'timeout')
    response = connection.put(url, data=data, params=params, headers=headers, timeout=timeout)

    print('[make_put_request]: [%s][%s][%s][%s]\n' %(url, data, params, headers))

    if response.ok or response.status_code == 403:
        return response.json() if response.content else None
    else:
        response.raise_for_status()
```

Prints out:

```
[make_put_request]: [https://developer-api.nest.com/devices/thermostats/DEVICE_ID/ambient_temperature_f.json?auth=VALID_AUTH_TOKEN][71][{}][{}]
```

Returns error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\py\nest_auth.py", line 90, in <module>
    put_result = firebase.put(data_url, field_name, 71)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\firebase\decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\firebase\firebase.py", line 312, in put
    connection=connection)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\firebase\decorators.py", line 19, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\firebase\firebase.py", line 77, in make_put_request
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 808, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request
```

---

This worked when using a [firebaseio.com](https://firebaseio.com) target but isn't working for Nest:

```
put_result = firebase.put('/devices/thermostats/DEVICE_ID/', 'ambient_temperature', 71)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/cloud/api-overview/#ambient_temperature_f) `ambient_temperature_f` is a read only field that represent's the reported ambient temperature from the thermostat. It wouldn't make sense to override that since it is a sensor reading.

I think you want to write to `target_temperature_f`, which is the temperature the thermostat should heat or cool to.

Comment: I did recently notice that but unfortunately I am still getting the same error. Using the Chrome Developer Tools for Nest, I could actually change the value displayed as the reported temperature. The Nest set it back to the actual thermostat value after a little while.

Comment: Is there a way to attach the desired value to the url much like how the access_token is? Something like appending `?value=71` for instance.

Comment: No, the REST API only accepts JSON payloads, not query parameters, and the Firebase API only speaks Firebase syntax.